# Find regex source from library eg. Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, regex, validation, hibernate-validator

I want to see regular expressions written by developers of any library for validation (eg. regex for email, data, post code etc.).

For example, here is [Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/) (implementation of [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/)) and it's code: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator

Where is in the code regexp for eg. `@Email`, `@CreditCardNumber`, `@DateTimeFormat`?

I tried searching the code like this: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=email.
I found `[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}`. But it is one regex. I want to see all regex.

I need this only for educational purposes. I know, I shoud USE library in real project, don't copy&paste regex.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to search for "regexp ="? https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=regexp+%3D&type=Code

Answer (score 2):

Not every constraint are regex-based and, in fact, the one you cited as example are not validated using a simple regex. The easiest way to see how a constraint is validated is to look at the Javadoc of the annotation and search for a `...Validator` class.

- [`@Email`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.html) is validated by [`EmailValidator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/EmailValidator.html). Looking at the source code, the validation is a bit more complex than a simple regex match (for example, the local and domain part are considered separately).
- [`@CreditCardNumber`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/CreditCardNumber.html) constraint does not implement a regex constraint (nor does it check validity of the credit card number). It uses the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to check for user mistake. It is therefore validated by [`LuhnCheckValidator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/LuhnCheckValidator.html).
- [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) is not a Hibernate annotation but a Spring annotation and it has nothing to do with Bean Validation API.